# How to install/enable pdo-odbc driver on a php docker container?

Tags: php, docker, pdo, odbc

I am currently having trouble writing a Dockerfile for my php application.
My Dockerfile works but lacks the pdo-odbc driver I need to connect to an MS SQL Server database. Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:apache
RUN apt-get install && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install tdsodbc unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y && \
    docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr && \
    docker-php-ext-enable pdo_odbc && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    service apache2 restart && \
    sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf && \
    sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf && \
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

The script crashes at the 6th line where I try to enable the extension:

```
error: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_odbc does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable [options] module-name [module-name ...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 0-apc.ini apcu apc

Possible values for module-name:

opcache.so sodium.so

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
```

I also tried to use docker-php-ext-install but still didn't work. How do we do to install or enable this extension?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
RUN apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y \
 && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc
```

Comment: i tried this and got this error
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package unixodbc
E: Unable to locate package unixodbc-dev
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y  && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: It worked after adding RUN "apt-get update &&" apt-get install...

Comment: Seriously I have been trying to fix this for like 2 days you are the best

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/103 you can try this:

```
FROM php
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unixODBC-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN set -x \
&& cd /usr/src/php/ext/odbc \
&& phpize \
&& sed -ri 's@^ *test +"\$PHP_.*" *= *"no" *&& *PHP_.*=yes *$@#&@g' configure \
&& ./configure --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
&& docker-php-ext-install odbc
```

Comment: This answer is for odbc, while the OP asks for pdo-odbc, which is something different. PHP and its module names are a mess! Upvoting anyway since that link helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y --force-yes

RUN docker-php-source extract
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc \
    && cd /usr/src/php/ext/odbc \
    && phpize \
    && sed -ri 's@^ *test +"\$PHP_.*" *= *"no" *&& *PHP_.*=yes *$@#&@g' configure \
    && ./configure --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install odbc
```